# Checkbox messes up entire listView

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-listview

I am trying to implement a checkbox into each listView item. The listView is a collection of all the users installed applications. The issue is, when I run my app and go to my listView, all I see is just one row (an application icon and then the checkbox right next to it), instead of there being a checkbox in each row. Here is my layout that defines the listView items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="5dip" 
>

<ImageView
  android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
  android:scaleType="center"
  android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
/>

<LinearLayout
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="0dip"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1"    
>

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tvName"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dip"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"         
  />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tvPack"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dip"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:ellipsize="marquee"         
  />

 </LinearLayout>

 <CheckBox
  android:id="@+id/addCheckbox"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:gravity="center_vertical" 
 />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then here is my custom adapter:

```
package com.example.awesomefilebuilderwidget;

IMPORTS

public class AppInfoAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
private Context mContext;
private List<ApplicationInfo> mListAppInfo;
private PackageManager mPackManager;
private List<ApplicationInfo> originalListAppInfo;
private Filter filter;

public AppInfoAdapter(Context c, List<ApplicationInfo> listApp, PackageManager pm) {
    mContext = c;
    this.originalListAppInfo = this.mListAppInfo = listApp;
    mPackManager = pm;
    }

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mListAppInfo.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mListAppInfo.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // get the selected entry
    ApplicationInfo entry = (ApplicationInfo) mListAppInfo.get(position);

    // reference to convertView
    View v = convertView;

    // inflate new layout if null
    if(v == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_appinfo, null);
    }

    // load controls from layout resources
    ImageView ivAppIcon = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ivIcon);
    TextView tvAppName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
    TextView tvPkgName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvPack);
    CheckBox addCheckbox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.addCheckbox);

    // set data to display
    ivAppIcon.setImageDrawable(entry.loadIcon(mPackManager));
    tvAppName.setText(entry.loadLabel(mPackManager));
    tvPkgName.setText(entry.packageName);
    addCheckbox.setChecked(true);
    checkButtonClick();

    // return view
    return v;
}

private void checkButtonClick() {
    // do nothing
}
```

My list worked fine until I added the checkbox. Why is it doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `weight`, you should be using `"0dp"` for your `width`. Change your `CheckBox` to

```
<CheckBox
   android:id="@+id/addCheckbox"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"   
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:gravity="center_vertical" 
   />
```

Comment: Fixed it, but now some of my text views are scrunched up so what would be a good weight since the checkbox doesn't need to take up much room

Comment: You will have to play with that as I don't know exactly what you want it to look like. Maybe try .5

Comment: Ok, I messed around with it and got what I wanted. Thanks anyways!